# PDF Generation from HTML page using JavaScript or Jquery Library or Plugin

Tags: javascript, pdf, shopify, jspdf

I am trying to convert an html page to PDF which contains images and some data-tables which as designed using css styles.
I have tried JSPDF and html2canvas libraries but the images don't show up in PDF and also they don't allow me to create PDF on long pages as my html is dynamic and it could grow into four pages.
I have searched so many forum's online but unable to find anything which resolves my issue.
The site in which i am implementing is shopify site. So any clue with this reference might help.
Any sort of help will be highly thankful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check at this link if it can be usefull for you on codepen

https://codepen.io/massimo-cassandro/pen/qOrJNx

```
<html>
  <!-- donot consider this i put it just to allow the link-->
<html/>
```

Comment: Hi. I have seen your mentioned link but they are assigning properties to each element from JavaScript but my html is dynamic i cant handle it through this if there is any other thing it would be great.

Comment: Hi, i'm very sorry i thought that could drive you througth any idea which could help you

Answer (score 0):

Transform the content of your html into image and then transform it into PDF :

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

```js
                  
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#btn-download').click(function () {
        html2canvas($('#container').html).then(function (canvas) { DownloadPDF(canvas) });
    });

    function DownloadPDF(canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                   'image/png');
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, parseInt($(canvas).attr('width')) / 9, parseInt($(canvas).attr('height')) / 9);
        doc.save('name.pdf');
    }
```

```css
#test
{
  width: 500px;
  height : 500px;
  background-image: url("https://www.wikichat.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/comment-soigner-une-plaie-dun-chat.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#btn-download
{
  cursor:pointer;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="btn-download">Download</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had already tried this before. but there are two issues in this first is that it doesn't allow me to go on more than 2 pages and also no images appear in this. as i have image and css styling in my html and for that it is not working properly.

Comment: it would be really great if you can create a fiddle for pdf creating along with images and css styling for multi-page layout plz

Comment: I dont think stackoverflow let the code snippet download thing but it should work like this for me